# Nodejs and DBaaS SQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, dbaas

I have looked at Google Cloud SQL and Amazon RDS, however, are there any services like this (or these) that have an npm module to write a CRUD application with a MySQL, Node, Express backend? All of the npm modules seem to be for NoSQL databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud SQL and Amazon RDS are just MySQL (https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql) or Postgres (https://www.npmjs.org/package/pg) under the hood. You don't need NPM packages specific to RDS or Cloud SQL.

Comment: so then would I just connect to the sql server via the domain name, username, and password?